# Two-way frequency table followed by matrix multiplication - high running time

Tags: r, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm new to R, and trying to calculate the product between a fixed matrix to a 2-way frequency table for any combinations of columns in a dataframe or matrix and divide it by the sequence length (aka number of rows which is 15), the problem is that the running time increases dramatically when performing it on 1K sequences (1K columns). the goal is to use it with as much as possible sequences (more than 10 minutes, for 10K could be more than 1hr)

```
mat1 <- matrix(sample(LETTERS),ncol = 100,nrow = 15)
mat2 <- matrix(sample(abs(rnorm(26,0,3))),ncol=26,nrow=26)
rownames(mat2) <- LETTERS
colnames(mat2) <- LETTERS
diag(mat2) <- 0

test_vec <- c()
for (i in seq(ncol(mat1)-1)){  
  for(j in seq(i+1,ncol(mat1))){
    
    s2 <- table(mat1[,i],mat1[,j]) # create 2-way frequency table
    mat2_1 <- mat2
    mat2_1 <- mat2_1[rownames(mat2_1) %in% rownames(s2), 
                               colnames(mat2_1) %in% colnames(s2)]
    calc <- ((1/nrow(mat1))*sum(mat2_1*s2))
    test_vec <- append(test_vec,calc)

  }}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that converts mat1 to a data.table, and converts all the columns to factors, and uses `table(..., exclude=NULL)`

```
library(data.table)
m=as.data.table(mat1)[,lapply(.SD, factor, levels=LETTERS)]
g = combn(colnames(m),2, simplify = F)
result = sapply(g, function(x) sum(table(m[[x[1]]], m[[x[2]]], exclude=NULL)*mat2)/nrow(m))
```

Check equality:

```
sum(result-test_vec>1e-10)
[1] 0
```

Here there are 4950 combinations (100*99/2), but the number of combinations will increase quickly as nrow(mat1) increases (as you point out).  You might find in that case that a parallelized version works well.

```
library(doParallel)
library(data.table)
registerDoParallel()

m=as.data.table(mat1)[,lapply(.SD, factor, levels=LETTERS)]
g = combn(colnames(m),2, simplify = F)
result = foreach(i=1:length(g), .combine=c) %dopar%
  sum(table(m[[g[[i]][1]]], m[[g[[i]][2]]], exclude=NULL)*mat2)
result = result/nrow(m)
```

Comment: First of all thank you.
Second thing is that the product of each 2-way Freq. table and mat2 should include only columns that appear in the 2-way freq table and adjust mat2 according to it.
So the final matrix before the summation should take only values that appeared in the 2-way Freq table and multiply it by the adjusted mat2 and the sum it up.
your solution is good but it takes all the values of mat2.

Comment: If this is a problem, can you help me understand why my result is the same as yours?.  aren't the extra values 0 and therefore don't effect the sum?

Comment: Youre correct. my bad.
ive created dummy dataset for the question here, but when i apply it on my dataset it returns "non-conformable arrays".
so im trying to adjust it to my data.
Thanks mate.